# Private variables and inherited constructors

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, private, super

I am new to Java, so i might have missed something here - i looked around in other threads, but i didn't find anything that quite resemble my question. i know that private variables are not inherited by the child class. the question that i am having, why did the super(); in my child constructor recognize the fields in my base constructor? is it bc the constructor in the parent class is public? and even though the variables it is passing are private, the child constructor will recognize them and pass them regardless? any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

parent class:

```
public abstract class BaseQuestion {

private String questions;
private float totalAttempts;
private float averageTime;
private float percentCorrect;

public BaseQuestion(String questions, float totalAttempts, float averageTime, float percentCorrect){
    this.questions = questions;
    this.totalAttempts = totalAttempts;
    this.averageTime = averageTime;
    this.percentCorrect = percentCorrect;
}
```

child class:

```
public class TrueFalseQuestion extends BaseQuestion{
public static int questionsCreated;


public TrueFalseQuestion(String question, float totalAttempts, float averageTime, float percentCorrect){
    super(question, totalAttempts, averageTime, percentCorrect);

}
```

the compiler gives me no error with the above, which confuses me a bit...

Thank you,

Comment: you are not referencing base class's private variabless in the call to super().  You are refencing derived class's constructor's parameters.  Parameters and instance variable are different and do not intersect.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor in the child class didn't "recognize" the fields in the superclass, it received some parameters which happen to have the same name as the attributes in the super class, but they're different in principle. They get assigned to the superclass' fields because you're invoking `super()` for accessing the superclass' constructor, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

```
super(question, totalAttempts, averageTime, percentCorrect);
```

In this line of code all the variable names refer to parameters in your child class. Their values are passed to the base class constructor which then assigns them to the private variables. The confusion is probably because the parameters and the private variables have the same names. However, you have to be careful which ones you are referring to. This is a common practice for constructors.